How convert CSV file into hierarchical json
today i have a modification from another question that i did yesterday.
The challenge is: How convert a CSV into a hierarchical json but the keys and values are different. It must be done with PYTHON (pandas and json library)
So i have the next CSV file:
TABLE_NAME,TIPO_CARGA,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE
CUENTAS,Full load,PERFIL,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS,Full load,LLAMADA_INI,DATE
CUENTAS,Full load,LLAMADA_END,DATE
CUENTAS_PLAN,Delta,REGISTRO,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_PLAN,Delta,ULTIMA_VISITA,DATE
CUENTAS_PLAN,Delta,FECHA,DATE
CUENTAS_TACTICAS,Delta,CIUDAD,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_TACTICAS,Delta,SALIDA,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_TACTICAS,Delta,COMPLETADO,DATE
CUENTAS_MIEMBROS,Full load,NEGOCIO,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_MIEMBROS,Full load,CORE,NVARCHAR2
CUENTAS_MIEMBROS,Full load,DESC,NVARCHAR2

The result must be something like this:
{
    "schema_name": {
        "CUENTAS": {
            "LOAD_TYPE": "Full load",
            "FIELDS": {
                "PERFIL": "NVARCHAR2",
                "LLAMADA_INI": "DATE",
                "LLAMADA_END": "DATE"
            }
        },
        "CUENTAS_PLAN": {
            "LOAD_TYPE": "Delta",
            "FIELDS": {
                "ULTIMA_VISITA": "DATE",
                "FECHA": "DATE",
                "CIUDAD": "NVARCHAR2"
            }
        },
        "CUENTAS_TACTICAS": {
            "LOAD_TYPE": "Delta",
            "FIELDS": {
                "CIUDAD": "NVARCHAR2",
                "SALIDA": "NVARCHAR2",
                "COMPLETADO": "DATE"
            }
        }
        {...}
    }
}

I prepare a python code to create a normal json structure like "key":"value", where key is a normalize text, and the value is the information from the CSV... but this does not meet the requirements.
Can somebody help me to create this python code?
Regards

Use nested dictionary comprehension with convert last columns to dictionary:
import json

out = (json.dumps({"schema_name": {n: {'LOAD_TYPE':l,'FIELDS': dict(g.to_numpy())}
                 for (n,l), g in 
                 df.groupby(['TABLE_NAME','TIPO_CARGA'], 
                            sort=False)[['COLUMN_NAME','DATA_TYPE']]}}))

print (out)
{
    "schema_name": {
        "CUENTAS": {
            "LOAD_TYPE": "Full load",
            "FIELDS": {
                "PERFIL": "NVARCHAR2",
                "LLAMADA_INI": "DATE",
                "LLAMADA_END": "DATE"
            }
        },
        "CUENTAS_PLAN": {
            "LOAD_TYPE": "Delta",
            "FIELDS": {
                "REGISTRO": "NVARCHAR2",
                "ULTIMA_VISITA": "DATE",
                "FECHA": "DATE"
            }
        }...


Use groupby and a dictionary comprehension:
out = json.dumps({
    'schema_name': {
        n: {'LOAD_TYPE': l, 'FIELDS': g.to_dict()}
        for (n, l), g in df.set_index('COLUMN_NAME').groupby(
            ['TABLE_NAME', 'TIPO_CARGA']
        )['DATA_TYPE']
    }
}, indent=2)

Output:
{
  "schema_name": {
    "CUENTAS": {
      "LOAD_TYPE": "Full load",
      "FIELDS": {
        "PERFIL": "NVARCHAR2",
        "LLAMADA_INI": "DATE",
        "LLAMADA_END": "DATE"
      }
    },
    "CUENTAS_MIEMBROS": {
      "LOAD_TYPE": "Full load",
      "FIELDS": {
        "NEGOCIO": "NVARCHAR2",
        "CORE": "NVARCHAR2",
        "DESC": "NVARCHAR2"
      }
    },
    "CUENTAS_PLAN": {
      "LOAD_TYPE": "Delta",
      "FIELDS": {
        "REGISTRO": "NVARCHAR2",
        "ULTIMA_VISITA": "DATE",
        "FECHA": "DATE"
      }
    },
    "CUENTAS_TACTICAS": {
      "LOAD_TYPE": "Delta",
      "FIELDS": {
        "CIUDAD": "NVARCHAR2",
        "SALIDA": "NVARCHAR2",
        "COMPLETADO": "DATE"
      }
    }
  }
}

